# Java JSF spintax contains cyclic references

Tags: java, jsf

I'm really new to JSF, I'm trying to make a simple app, which takes content like {a|b|c} {a|b|c} and genarate random variation like a c or b a etc. I've made a class which will be my managed bean (It's ok for sure):

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Spintax implements Serializable {

    private String spinText;

    public void setSpinText(String spinText) {
        this.spinText = spinText;
    }

    public String setSpintax(String spinText) {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        String pat = "\\{[^{}]*\\}";
        Pattern ma;
        ma = Pattern.compile(pat);
        Matcher mat = ma.matcher(spinText);
        while (mat.find()) {
            String segono = spinText.substring(mat.start() + 1, mat.end() - 1);
            String[] choies = segono.split("\\|", -1);
            spinText = spinText.substring(0, mat.start())
                    + choies[rnd.nextInt(choies.length)].toString()
                    + spinText.substring(mat.start() + mat.group().length());
            mat = ma.matcher(spinText);
        }
        return spinText;
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to get String from simple form, use the class above to generate random variation an set response as a new String.

Here's my faces-confix.xml:

```
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>spintax</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>resources.Spintax</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
        <managed-property>
            <property-name>spinText</property-name>
            <property-class>java.lang.String</property-class>
            <value>#{spintax.spintext}</value>
        </managed-property>
    </managed-bean>
```

Here's a part of index.xhtml where user puts Strig like {a|b|c} {a|b|c}:

```
    <h:form>
                <h:inputText value="#{spintax.spintext}" />
                <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="result" />
              </h:form></p>
```

Here's a part of my result.xhtml where new String should show up:

```
    <p><h:outputText value="#{spintax.spintext}" /></p>
```

What am I doing wrong ? I get:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Unable to create managed bean spintax. The following problems were found:

javax.servlet.ServletException: Unable to create managed bean spintax.  The following problems were found: Managed bean spintax contains cyclic references.  Evaluation path: spintax -> spintax. javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659) org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you trying to reference `<value>#{spintax.spintext}</value>` the same manage bean that is being created `<managed-bean-name>spintax</managed-bean-name>`:

```xml
<managed-property>
    <property-name>spinText</property-name>
    <property-class>java.lang.String</property-class>
    <value>#{spintax.spintext}</value>
</managed-property>
```

If you need to pass the value of `spintext` to the next request, you can use the tag `f:param` as follows:

**index.xhtml**:

```xml
<h:form>
    <h:inputText value="#{spintax.spintext}" />
    <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="result">
        <f:param name="spintext" value="#{spintax.spintext}" />
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

**faces-config.xml**:

```xml
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>spintax</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>resources.Spintax</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>spinText</property-name>
        <property-class>java.lang.String</property-class>
        <value>#{param.spintext}</value>
    </managed-property>
</managed-bean>
```

> **f:param**
>   The Param tag sets a parameter for the component associated with the
>   enclosing tag. You can use it to you build compound messages by
>   replacing placeholder values in an outputFormat tag. The body content
>   of the param tag must be empty. See also the HTML outputFormat tag.

See: http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/core/f_param.html

I hope this help.